# How to mutate the negative values of some columns into positive in my data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, absolute

i have the following issue:

In my data frame (89 columns) I have 4 of them which have the values in a negative way as you can see in the following image

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFF0U.png

So I would like to know how I could mutate that specific columns of my data frame in order to make the values of them positive (absolute value).

Many thanks

Comment: Please help us help you by making a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Give us a sample of your data by using `dput(head(mydata)` and pasting the output into your question. Then we can copy your data directly into R. Rebuilding your data from an image (with a link that could rot) is tedious.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  mutate(across(c("DAYS_BIRTH", "DAYS_EMPLOYED", "DAYS_REGISTRATION", "DAYS_ID_PUBLISH"), abs))
```

Depending on which columns you want to mutate and which you want to leave, you might be able to use a simpler select helper, like `mutate(across(starts_with("DAYS"), abs))`, for example.

Comment: A slightly simpler version: `your_data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("DAYS"), abs))`

Answer (score 0):

A general solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate_if(function(x) all(x<0), function(x) abs(x))
```